# Pushing a state to page history and then replacing an existing state with it

Tags: javascript

I found this 18 rows Javascript code that as I understand, pushes a state to the memory, and then replaces it with another existing state, so that the webpage's DOM content will change. The code uses to replace data that was loaded with AJAJ instead directly from PHP (given that setTimeout and setInterval didn't help to change it).

```
var run = (run)=> {
   // insert your code here
};

var pS = window.history.pushState;
var rS = window.history.replaceState;

window.history.pushState = (a, b, url)=> {
    run(url);
    pS.apply(this, arguments);
};

window.history.replaceState = (a, b, url)=> {
    run(url);
    rS.apply(this, arguments);
};

})();
```

There is an `unrecoverable syntax error` in line 16 (`};`). Why is it there? As a JS newbie I don't have the slightest idea - I read about closures and tried to read the code about 4 times but didn't recognize anything wrong with the closures, and I tried to look for syntax errors or typos in keywords/names/syntax but didn't find any.

I feel as something is wrong with the logic of the code and that in this stage of my studies, I think I lack enough knowledge to find the problem.

Comment: add a `(` before the first line and it should get rid of the error `(var run = (run)=> {`

Comment: pasting it in the TypeScript playground might give some clues  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ where did you get the code from? the last line seems out of place

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald now I get `Expected an identifier and instead saw var`.

Comment: @Slai I got it from [here](https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=2247).

Comment: thre's hanging crap on the bottom, just get rid of the last line `})();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line has a `}` and a `)` that is not paired with an opening `{` and `(`.

My Conclusion:

1. They were placed there by mistake
2. You did not include the entire file/code
3. Or they are part of an IIFE *(Immediately Invoked Function Expression)* that is missing its opening

I'll assume **Number 3**, and provide the solution to **Number 3**

```
(function(){
    var run = (run)=> {
       // insert your code here
    };

    var pS = window.history.pushState;
    var rS = window.history.replaceState;

    window.history.pushState = (a, b, url)=> {
        run(url);
        pS.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    window.history.replaceState = (a, b, url)=> {
        run(url);
        rS.apply(this, arguments);
    };

})();
```

As you can see on **line 1**, I added `(function(){` to match the closing bracket and parenthesis

Comment: Indeed it was the case, thank you so much. Your answer sharpened my understanding. If I see an IIFE ending I will always make sure there is a relevant opener and will more probably do a similar check in other similar opener-closer situations.